# UITableView setting row Height not having effect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Why is it that when I set `tableView.rowHeight = 100` in `viewDidLoad()` I always get the default height value of 44.0? I tried setting `tableView.estimatedHeight =100` as well but no luck, I tried setting the delegate method `tableView.heightForRowAt` as well but that doesn't seem to have any effect as well what so ever. So the question is: how do you set the height for a tableView Cell?

```
    override func viewDidLoad(){ // tableView viewDidLoad
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = 100
    tableView.register(TickerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
    // Custom Cell Init 
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    backgroundColor = .clear
    print(frame.height) // always prints 44.0
    let symbolstack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [symbolLabel,companyLabel])
    let sectorstack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [sectorLabel,exchangeLabel])
    let mainStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [symbolstack,sectorstack])
    sectorstack.axis = .vertical
    symbolstack.axis = .vertical
    sectorstack.alignment = .trailing
    symbolstack.alignment = .leading
    symbolstack.distribution = .fillEqually
    sectorstack.distribution = .fillEqually
    mainStack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    addSubview(mainStack)
    mainStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    mainStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -45).isActive = true
    mainStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    addSubview(WatchlistStar)
    WatchlistStar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    WatchlistStar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
    WatchlistStar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainStack.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    WatchlistStar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
    WatchlistStar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

So the problem appears to be in the fact then in the cell init method the rowHeight I set In viewDidLoad does not seem to register, only in `prepareForReuse` when I print `frame.height` do I get 100 printed,So in which method do I setup the cell layout then?

Comment: I don't know why but when I set heightConstraint for the content view equal that of the cell it seems to work and size the cell correctly, but when I use frames it doesn't work

Comment: @matt No there is no storyboard. Is there some kind of variable I need to set on the tableView to let me set the height?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any detail, but are you using a mix of autoLayout constraints and trying to set explicit frame sizes, resulting in the constraints overwriting the frame settings?

Comment: Well, I'm happy to retract my answer.

Comment: But then please show in detail how table view is created and configured

Comment: Very good improvement to the question.

Comment: But you are using autolayout so you should not care what the frame is, right? Everything will adjust itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell is not born knowing its height, so `init` is a pointless place to look at the frame. In fact, it has no inherent height. Cells are reused. They take on a height only in relation to a particular row of the table where they are being used right at the moment. That height can change when the cell is used in a different row (because rows can be different heights). So your layout needs to cope with that.

In the code you have shown, you are using autolayout. The whole point of autolayout is that you don't care about the frame of things at any one moment. Everything adjusts automatically as the surrounding frame changes. Autolayout is about *relationships*.

So the solution in that case is: *don't* look at `frame.height`. You don't need to know it. Just lay out the relationships between the views and the cell, and everything will be correct when the cell appears, if you have used autolayout correctly.

On the other hand, as you now say in a comment "Im forced to [use autolayout] not because I want to" — okay, so if the goal is to do layout manually, like we did before there was autolayout, then the place to do it is in the data source's `cellForRowAt:`. Or you *could* try doing it in the cell's `layoutSubviews` if you want the cell to lay itself out. See the old edition of my book, online, for how we used to do this: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells

Be very careful to distinguish between adding subviews and resizing them. You don't want to make the mistake of adding subviews that you have already added. So add the subviews in `init`, sure, as it is called only once, but size them in a place where the actual size of the row has been communicated to the cell.

One more piece of advice. Your current code uses the phrase `addSubview`, meaning `self.addSubview`. That is totally wrong and illegal. Never never add a subview directly to a cell. Add it only to the cell's `contentView`, and size it in relation to that.

Comment: Yes, Im using auto layout because Im forced to do so not because I want to.I posted this question because my initial cell layout was using frames, I just did it in auto layout instead to fix the height problem.

Comment: But still that doesn't explain why the cell height is not being set properly in the cell init

Comment: Yes it does explain that.

Comment: "Im forced to do so not because I want to" aha - that's what I needed to know

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40 
}
```

Comment: If you set rowHeight to automatic the tableView decides the height so this is not how you set the height manually